# Why do not Convert bitmap to Imgae?

Tags: emgucv

private readonly Tesseract _ocrEngine = new Tesseract("tessdata", "eng", OcrEngineMode.Default);

```
    private void GlobalHookHandler(object sender, MacroEvent e)
    {
        if (!IsRecording)
            return;

        var bmpScreenshot = CaptureScreen();

        if (e.KeyMouseEventType == MacroEventType.KeyUp || e.KeyMouseEventType == MacroEventType.KeyDown)
        {
            var keyEvent = (KeyEventArgs)e.EventArgs;
            switch (keyEvent.KeyCode)
            {
                case RECORD_KEY_HOOK:
                case PLAY_KEY_HOOK:
                    return;
            }
        }

        switch (e.EventArgs)
        {
            case MouseEventExtArgs mouseEvent:
                e.EventArgs = new MouseEventArgs(mouseEvent.Button, mouseEvent.Clicks, mouseEvent.X, mouseEvent.Y, mouseEvent.Delta);
                break;
            case KeyEventArgsExt keyEvent:
                e.EventArgs = new KeyEventArgs(keyEvent.KeyData);
                break;
            case KeyPressEventArgsExt keyPressEvent:
                e.EventArgs = new KeyPressEventArgs(keyPressEvent.KeyChar);
                break;
        }

        Image<Bgr, byte> imageCV = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bmpScreenshot);

        // OCR 실행
        _ocrEngine.SetImage(imageCV);
        _ocrEngine.Recognize();
        // 인식된 텍스트 가져오기
        string recognizedText = _ocrEngine.GetUTF8Text();

        var lastAction = _actionFile.Actions.LastOrDefault();
        _actionFile.Actions.Add(e);
        var timeSinceLastEvent = lastAction == null ? "0" : lastAction.TimeSinceLastEvent.ToString();
        Log($"[A:{_actionFile.Actions.Count}] [LT:{timeSinceLastEvent}] {e.KeyMouseEventType} recorded. [Recongized text:{recognizedText}]");
    }

    private Bitmap CaptureScreen()
    {
        var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        return bmpScreenshot;
    }
```

Image<Bgr, byte> imageCV = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bmpScreenshot);
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression Error (Suppression) Status
Error CS1503 1 Argument: Cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'byte[*,*,*]'